# Play a video from a url in default player in Native SDK for BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-q10

I am developing an application for playing video from a url in bb10 cascades.I know it's very simple to play in media player.Please help me to play a video in default player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you review the documentation provided on the BB10 Native micro-site that you will find here:

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/

I know there is a lot to look at, but it does seem to me to be quite logically presented.  I just looked round and fairly quickly found this:

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/graphics_multimedia/audio_video/playing_audio_or_video.html

which seems to answer your question.  Alternatively, you want want to just invoke the native player, in which case you need to look here:

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/invocation_framework.html